# For what type of relationships can "関係" be used?

Tags: word-choice, words, word-usage

I am writing a text about relationships between different generations and would like to know is [関係]{かんけい} an appropriate word in this context.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. You can explicitly say human relationship with 人間関係.